# Oracle Extended Stored Procedure with C++

Tags: c++, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I am currently adding Oracle 10.2.0. as a viable database to a product. The product originally allows connection to SQL Server and I have found some extended stored procedures.

Is it possible to produce similar extended stored procedures for Oracle with C++?

If so, how do I accomplish this? Example code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [Oracle External Procedures](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_extern_proc.htm#i1018255).

[Here is a discussion](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=318364) on getting the environment set up properly - it's tricky.

Asktom.com has an i[nteresting discussion.](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:16212348050)

Be aware there are [several security issues](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=strict&q=oracle+extproc+10g+security&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) to be concerned with.